# Laravel route where locale is sometimes not the first in the URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization

I have set a locale. 
The url should usually start with http://example.com/en/...../.....

But for some(not all!) routes I would like to add something in front of the locale.
for example http://example.com/api/settings/en/...../.....

Is that even possible with the standard LaravelLocalization or what could be a solution to this?

thx in advance

edit:
my routing files all start with something like

```
    // Index page
    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'index',
        function () {
            return view('index');
        }, ]);

    // Campaign mode
    Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'campaign',
        'as'
```

So there is no language set in the routes itself

Comment: Add your routes code here please.

Answer (score 0):

Place your API routes above the language group of routes

```
$router->group(['prefix'=>'api'], function($router)
{
    $router->get('/', 'APIController@index');
});

// This would product api/

$router->group(['prefix'=>'{lang?}'], function($router)
{
    $router->get('home', 'HomeController@index');
});

// This would produce /en/home
```

Your routes of course will be different, but that's the gist

Comment: The problem is, that I dont even have the language set in my routing files, they all start with
// Index page
Route::get('/', [
 'as' => 'index',
 function () {
  return view('index');
 }, ]);

// Campaign mode
Route::group([
 'prefix' => 'campaign',
for example so i guess it has to be set by laravel itself

Comment: Maybe you should rethink how your routes are laid out?